# Using Atril PDF viewer how can I start where I left off when I reopen a document?

Tags: pdf

I have just started using Atril to read PDF files.

For some reason whenever I reopen a document it starts on page-1.

Instead of starting where I left off.

Is there a setting I am missing?

I am using Atril 1.2.6, with openbox-wm.

I do have read/write access to the pdf file if that makes a difference.